# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar fechas pasadas en Español? PHP

Tags: php, date

Muy buenas a todos!

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas con este tema ya que todo lo que he leído está enfocado a traducir la fecha de ese mismo día a español. En mi caso, necesito mostrar siempre el mes anterior al actual, también será necesario hacer lo mismo con el año cada vez que lleguemos a enero. El día es indiferente. El lenguaje empleado es PHP.

He probado con  `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');` y `strftime();` pero no he logrado el resultado que busco. Este es el código que actualmente muestra el mes en inglés:

`$lastMonth = date('F', strtotime("-1 month"));`

¿Existe alguna variante o función aplicable a esa o que resulte igual de sencilla para obtener el mes anterior en español?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución la tienes en usar una mezcla de las dos vías que has explorado. Usando la función `strtotime()` podrías obtener la fecha actual menos un mes y a través de `strftime()` y de `setlocale()` transformarla al formato español.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
echo strftime("%B", strtotime("- 1 month"));
```

Esto devolvería:

```
enero
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @phpMyGuel ! Me había faltado el `"%B"` dentro de `strftime()`. Ya me veía condenado a utilizar un enorme switch... :P